# Sagemaker lifecycle config: could not find conda environment conda_python3 & Any other Environment is not found

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

```html
#!/bin/bash
set -e
ENVIRONMENT=python3
NOTEBOOK_FILE="/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/untitled.ipynb"
source activate python3
nohup jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=600 --ExecutePreprocessor.kernel_name=conda_python3 --execute "$NOTEBOOK_FILE" &
```

The Above script which i use to start my notebook file "untitled.ipynb" when my sagemaker notebook instnace starts.

But when i start my notebook instance i am getting an error "Could not find conda environment: python3"

if any one knows the solution please post.

Answer (score 0):

When you run lifecycle config, you need to specify the activate script path where anaconda resides (and typically where the environments are then).

Then just modify the code part like this:

```bash
ENVIRONMENT=python3
source /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/activate "$ENVIRONMENT";
```

---

You can also see official examples of various configurations in this repo:

[amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/tree/master/scripts)